# Spring security - configuring classes | AuthenticationManagerBuilder

Tags: java, spring, security

I am trying to configure class that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.

```
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
}
```

and in the class I have such defined function:

```
   @Override
   protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception 
   {        
   auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
   .withUser("poef").password("fump")
   .roles("ACTUATOR ");
   }
```

My source is [HERE](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/builders/AuthenticationManagerBuilder.html) My problem in understanding is in the beginning of this statement:

```
.withUser("poef")
```

I don't see in doccumentation this function(withUser). Where it does come from the following statements.

Comment: Could you explain the term in memory authentication in spring. What does it exactly mean?

Comment: You don't rely on external authentication, no database or other servers involved. Just authenticate within the current  _in memory_ context

Answer (score 0):

The method`auth.inMemoryAuthentication()` returns an `InMemoryUserDetailsManagerConfigurer`, which, in turn, derives from 
[UserDetailsManagerConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configurers/provisioning/UserDetailsManagerConfigurer.html#withUser-java.lang.String-) that provides the `withUser()` method.

The `withUser()` returns a  `UserDetailsManagerConfigurer.UserDetailsBuilder` that provides the `password(..)` method.

Comment: and this user and password is visible in all the application?

Comment: Yes. Depending on your approach, possibly in an UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken